# How to "globalize" PHP variables?

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a page named ChangeApprovalInfo.php - It has a function called Row_Rendered as follows;

```
function Row_Rendered() {

    // To view properties of field class, use:
    //var_dump($this-><FieldName>);

    $RecordOwner = $this->RequestUser->CurrentValue;  
        echo $RecordOwner;
}
```

Echoing $RecordOwner gets me the data I will need for a sql query on another page....

I have another page called ChangeApprovalEdit.php - This page has

```
<?php include_once "ChangeApprovalinfo.php" ?>
```

at the top of the file.

ChangeApprovalEdit.php has a function where I need the $RecordOwner variable as defined in ChangedApprovalInfo.php

If I add "echo $RecordOwner" on the ChangeApprovalEdit.php page, I get an error saying it's an unknown variable. My understanding is that I need to "make it global" or some such business. I know very little about PHP and the pages I am editing are long and complex. (to me, at least)

- What do I need to do? I know that the information I have provided might not be enough to answer the question. I don't know enough to even know exactly what I need to ask. If more information is needed, I will edit and follow up.

pastebin of the files

```
ChangeApprovalInfo.php = http://pastebin.com/bSRM1wwN
ChangeApprovalEdit.php = http://pastebin.com/AStG9pqb
```

EDIT: 
Changing Row_Rendered to this seems to be more effective. I'm having trouble seeing WHERE I can later echo this variable... but I'm getting somewhere with this...

```
function Row_Rendered() {
    // To view properties of field class, use:
    //var_dump($this-><FieldName>);
    $GLOBALS['RecordOwner'] = $this->RequestUser->CurrentValue;  
}
```

Comment: Do what you wish, but be advised that you'll end up with a big ball of mud if you keep using global variables. This really calls for a `return` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `echo` variables from functions, which just outputs them to the standard output. `return` them from the function so you can use the value elsewhere as well.

```
function Row_Rendered() {
    $RecordOwner = $this->RequestUser->CurrentValue;  
    return $RecordOwner;
}
```

Then instead of

```
$obj->Row_Rendered();
```

use

```
echo $obj->Row_Rendered();
```

and if you want to use the value elsewhere, use

```
$value = $obj->Row_Rendered();
```

Comment: Just an add on this, if you have a lot of variables in your function return an array or an object !

Answer (score 2):

You can do a couple of things:

First, you can return `$RecordOwner` from the function, and store its value in a variable. This method is usually preferred.

```
function Row_Rendered() {

    // To view properties of field class, use:
    //var_dump($this-><FieldName>);

    $RecordOwner = $this->RequestUser->CurrentValue;  
        echo $RecordOwner;

    return $RecordOwner;
} 

// Store it in a variable when calling the function.
$RecordOwner = Row_Rendered();
```

Or, you can make it global inside the function:

```
function Row_Rendered() {

    // To view properties of field class, use:
    //var_dump($this-><FieldName>);

    $GLOBALS['RecordOwner'] = $this->RequestUser->CurrentValue;  
        echo $GLOBALS['RecordOwner'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$GLOBALS` superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array, like this:

```
function Row_Rendered() {
  $GLOBALS['RecordOwner'] = $this->RequestUser->CurrentValue;  
}
```

However, you *should not do that*. Instead, refactor your application so that the view in `ChangeApprovalinfo.php` just contains a function, which is then called with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: Chaning Row_Rendered to this seems to be more effective. I'm having trouble seeing WHERE I can later echo this variable... but I'm getting somewhere with this...
>
> ```
> function Row_Rendered() {
>     // To view properties of field class, use:
>     //var_dump($this-><FieldName>);
>     $GLOBALS['RecordOwner'] = $this->RequestUser->CurrentValue;  
> }
> ```

I feel compelled to write another answer to this update. Let me demonstrate the use of globals as seen from *outside* that function:

```
$obj->Row_Rendered();
$obj->foobar();

echo $GLOBALS['RecordOwner'];
```

Quick, what will be `echo`ed and where does that value come from? Well, it depends on what `$obj-foobar()` does. Maybe it changes the global variable. Maybe it doesn't. Who knows if the variable has been set at all? How would you trace back what happened exactly without adding a debug line after every single function call?

And that's just three lines of code. Imagine that in an application of any complexity.

Now, the same thing if I `return` the value from `Row_Rendered`:

```
$owner = $obj->Row_Rendered();
$obj->foobar();

echo $owner;
```

If the `Row_Rendered` method is behaving as it should (returning the owner), this code is very predictable. If you do not follow this pattern, you'll have a hell of a time getting anything done when the application grows to any halfway complex size.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable as global from within the function

```
$my_global_var = "old value";

function doing_stuff(){
  global $my_global_var; //this will use the global variable instead of creating a local one
  $my_global_var = "new value";
}

echo $my_global_var;//returns "new value"
```