# How can i define a variable available to all php files(like superglobals)

Tags: php, global-variables

Is there a way to create/define a variable available to all php files(like superglobals)

> Example:
>
> i define a variable in **file1.php** `$car = ferrari`
>
> then in **file2.php** i write `echo $car;`
>
> then it will output `ferrari`

how can i define a variable in file1.php and access it in file2.php

**EDIT:**

The answers is good, but do is there another alternative?because i will have multiple php files in multiple directories, do i have to create its own php file for each directory?if thats the only way, then i'll do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "globalize" PHP variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845447/how-to-globalize-php-variables)

Answer (score 5):

- create init.php in your project's root directory.

If you need constant variable (so, you can't edit it)
- create constants.php in your project's root dir.

If you need editable variable
- create globals.php in your project's root dir.

**constants.php**

```
<?php
define('CAR', 'ferrari');
```

**globals.php**

```
<?php

class Globals
{
  public static $car = 'ferrari';
}
```

include **constants.php** and **globals.php** to **init.php**.

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'constants.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'globals.php');
```

include **init.php** to php sources.

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'init.php');
```

If you need variable for long use, not only one pageload, then use session. (user logins, settings, ...)

```
<?php
$_SESSION['car'] = 'ferrari';
```

In your php sources, you can use constant and global variables:

Example:

```
<?php
echo CAR; //ferrari

echo Globals::$car; //ferrari

Globals::$car = 'renault'; //set your global variable

echo Globals::$car; //renault
```

**Refs:**

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 1):

Create one constant file and include it in file in where you want to access those constants.

Include file as

```
include 'file_path';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SESSION` or `include` concept.

1) By using `SESSION`

**file1.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['car'] = 'ferrari';
```

**file2.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['car'];  //Result: ferrari
```

2) By using `include`

**file2.php**

```
include 'file1.php';
echo $car //Result: ferrari
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi The best way to do this is,

You make a .php file called "defines.php" and make sure to include that file in your each .php files.

make your variables, constants sits in that file. So that you can access them.

Other method would be, you can set the values to a existing Global variable.

like,

`$_SERVER['car'] = "ferrari"`

Thanks.